# Update database record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to update an existing record in a table of profiles using C# MVC.

I need to make 2 separate registration forms.

I have already done the first one and it's working as planned which creates the user record in the database with basic info.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Registration signingUp)
    {
        var db = new ShareRideDBEntities();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Data = db.tblProfiles.Create();

            Data.Prof_Email = signingUp.Email;
            Data.Prof_Password = signingUp.Password;
            db.tblProfiles.Add(Data);

            int Saved = db.SaveChanges();

            if (Saved != 0)
            {
                Response.Write("Success.");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Error.");
            }
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (ValidateUser(signingUp.Email, signingUp.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(signingUp.Email, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Members");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

What I want to do now is add to that existing record some new info using another form.

The form is asking for his name, last name, phone number and an option (with radio buttons) if he/she is a male or female.

If you need more info please comment, I'll put it asap.

EDIT:

on my `Model`

```
public class Registration
{
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

on my second `model`

```
public class ServiceRegistration
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I still don't have a the `HttpPost` method done for the second registration since I am not sure how to do it.

EDIT:

Ok so I have made a few changes base on the answer I got

My `ServiceRegistration.cs` model

```
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ShareRide.Models.Service
{
    public class ServiceRegistration
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings= false, ErrorMessage="Necesary Field.")]
        public string FirstName{ get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Necesary Field.")]
        public string LastName{ get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Necesary Field.")]
        public string Phone{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

on my `MembersController.cs` controller

```
public ActionResult Registrationform()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Registrationform(Guid UserID)
    {
        var model = new ServiceRegistration { UserID = UserID };

            return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registrationform(ServiceRegistration model)
    {
        var db = new ShareRideDBEntities();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Data = db.tblProfiles.Create();

            Data.PROF_UserID = model.UserID;
            Data.PROF_FirstName = model.Home_Address;
            Data.PROF_LastName = model.Work_Address;
            Data.PROF_Phone = model.Travel_Days;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Members");

        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now I'm getting an error on `model.UserID;` `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to 'int'`

On my database `PROF_UserID` is the primary key and is an `int`.

Also I commented the `Data.PROF_UserID = model.UserID;` so I could build but when I try to access the `Registrationform` view it returns an error:
[image: View error]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It's probably easier if you use JavaScript to create a multi-page form and send all data at once with your action call

Comment: @IsabelHM the thing is that I am forced to do it this way cause the purpose of the second form is another service included in our website which is only available for people already registered.

Comment: Have you tried to return the username or assigned tokenID (better) in the ViewBag, then assign a hidden form input box with the value when you submit the second form?

Comment: @IsabelHM I wish I could do what you say, but I'm still at an early stage of programming so I wouldn't know how to do what you're saying without a briefly explained example. Sorry...

Comment: So you can return the id of first record that is inserted and after that update that in second form

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to amend your ServiceRegistration model to take in your user id so we can attach it to our entity. I've also added data annotations for validation purposes but you can choose to ignore these if you like.

```
public class ServiceRegistration
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Phone { get; set; }

}
```

Next you need two actions. One to serve the form from a GET request and one save the record from a POST request.

Notice how we're passing the user's id over

```
public ActionResult AddUserInfo(int id)
{
    var model = new ServiceRegistration{ id = id }

    return View(model);
}
```

Im not sure how your dbContext is finding or adding users so you will need to add this yourself

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUserInfo(ServiceRegistration model)
{

    var db = new ShareRideDBEntities();

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //Find your user in your db context using model.Id as the reference

        //Add the User Data from the model

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller");

    }   

    //Form isn't valid so return form will the validation errors
    return View(model);

}
```

And finally your view should be named AddUserInfo and should look like this

```
@model my.namespace.ServiceRegistration

@using(Html.BeginForm(“AddUserInfo”, “Controller”, HttpMethod.Post))
{
    <!--Hide the id from the user-->
    Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

    Html.TextboxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    Html.TextboxFor(m => m.LastName)
    Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Phone)

    Html.ValidationSummary();

    <input type=“submit” value=“Save” />
}
```

I've just wrote this on my mac's notepad application so there maybe a couple of syntax errors, so I apologise in advance.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, im getting an error on `Data.PROF_UserID = model.UserID;` note that I changed your example `id` to `UserID` in my database the name of column is `PROF_UserID`, the error is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to 'int'`

Comment: Its telling you that Prof_UserID is of type int not Guid. So your UserId model needs to be of type int. Ill update my answer to reflect this new information

Comment: Also if your user id is auto incremented in the database you do not need to set it before hand.

Comment: I've made quite a few changes to this since yesterday and I'm still not able to get what I want. I opened a new question explaining the new errors and doubts I have. If you want I can paste the link for the question here?

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the user to a different view page, you need to use TempData instead of ViewBag. Here is a rough draft of code sample. You may need to modify it to fit your needs.

Model

```
public class Registration
{
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ServiceRegistration ServiceRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

In your HTTPPOST call, add one line in the validateuser condition statement

```
if (ValidateUser(signingUp.Email, signingUp.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(signingUp.Email, false);
        TempData["Registration"] = signingUp;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Members");
    }
```

View

```
@{
    var tempRegistration = TempData["Registration"] as Registration
}

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email, new { id = "email", value= tempRegistration})
```